# glm::translate - does it build matrix from a vector?

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glm-math, coordinate-transformation

The function `glm::translate` takes 2 arguments (matrix **M** , vector **V**). Am I right in assuming the following :

1. It multiplies the **M** with **V**
2. Makes a new Identity matrix
3. Puts the elements of the vector in the correct spots in the identity matrix
4. Returns the resulting matrix

Comment: `glm::translate` creates a translation matrix, which is tranlated by `V`. Then it multiplies `M` by the translation matrix and this is the result.

Comment: @Rabbid76 What happens if you want to have the choice of which order the matrices are multiplied? Like the difference between local translation or global translation. Does this function only allow you to multiply it in one particular way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly What it conceptually does is two things:

1. It creates a 4x4 homogenous translation matrix **T** which has the effect of offsetting every point by the vector **V**:

   ```
       / 1 0 0 Vx \
   T = | 0 1 0 Vy |
       | 0 0 1 Vz |
       \ 0 0 1 1  /
   ```

   so that for every point **p**=(px,py,pz,1)  **p'** = **T** * **p** will result in **p'** = **p** + **V**:

   ```
   / 1 0 0 Vx \      / px \      / px * 1 + 1 * Vx \
   | 0 1 0 Vy |   *  | py |  =   | py * 1 + 1 * Vy |
   | 0 0 1 Vz |      | pz |      | pz * 1 + 1 * Vz |
   \ 0 0 1 1  /      \ 1  /      \        1        /
   ```
2. It post-multiplies **T** to **M** and returns the result: **M'** = **M** * **T**

   This has the effect that applying **M'** to any point will first apply **T**, anfd then apply whatever was in **M** before:

   **p'** = **M'** * **p** = **M** * **T** * **p** = **M** * (**T** * **p**)

Note that the general matrix multiplication scheme can be simplified if one knows that one of the operands is a translation matrix. In the case of post-mulitplying **T**, this has the same effect of first transforming **V** by **M**, and than adding the resulting vector to the last column of **M**.

```
    / m00 m01 m02 m03 \     / 1 0 0 Vx \      / m00 m01 m02 (m03 + m00 * Vx + m01 * Vy + m02 * Vz) \
    | m10 m11 m12 m13 |  *  | 0 1 0 Vy |  =   | m10 m11 m12 (m13 + m10 * Vx + m11 * Vy + m12 * Vz) |
    | m20 m21 m22 m23 |     | 0 0 1 Vz |      | m20 m21 m22 (m23 + m20 * Vx + m21 * Vy + m22 * Vz) |
    \ m30 m31 m32 m33 /     \ 0 0 1 1  /      \ m30 m31 m32 (m33 + m30 * Vx + m31 * Vy + m32 * Vz) /
```

So no, it does not return an identity matrix where the translation part is replaced by **M** * **V**, it returns **M'** where **M** * **V** was *added* to the translation part.

Comment: By postmultiplying the translation matrix it results in local translation right? I was just reading what you wrote about simplifying the multiplication, I'm interested in this for optimisation, but I didn't quite get you. I know that if you want to translate in global coordinates and not local, you can just add the translation vector to the appropriate column/row, but if you want to translate locally, the equivalent of a post-multiply as done here, is there a way of optimising it?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, seeing as though the translation matrix is mostly 1 and 0 from the identity, there's a whole bunch of multiplications you can skip. This is a really neat trick for optimisation in my game engine.

Comment: @Zebrafish: There's another way to look at those things: Let T(v) be a translation matrix for translation vector v, and M be some generic transformation matrix. If you want to translate after M is applied, you can compose this to a single matrix T(v) * M, which is just v added to the rightmost column of M. If you want to translate first, you get M * T(v), which is the same as if you do the M transformation first, and afterwards translate by the _also transformed_ vector v' = M *v, so M * T(v) = T(M*v) * M, which means it is equal to just adding the vector v'=M*v to the translation column of M.

Answer (score 1):

See the [glm 0.9.8 API Documentation for `glm::translate`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.8/api/a00169.html#gaee134ab77c6c5548a6ebf4e8e476c6ed):

> **`glm::translate`**
>
> ```
> GLM_FUNC_DECL tmat4x4<T, P> glm::translate( 
>     tmat4x4< T, P > const & m,
>     tvec3< T, P >   const & v 
> )
> ```
>
> **Builds a translation 4*4 matrix created from a vector of 3 components**.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `m` **Input matrix multiplied by this translation matrix**.
> - `v` Coordinates of a translation vector.

This means that a transformation matrix is formed by the vector `v`

```
glm::vec3 v;

glm::mat4 t(
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    v.x,  v.y,  v.z,  1.0f );
```

and the result is the multiplication of the input matrix `m` and the translation matrix `t`:

```
glm::mat4 m;

glm::mat4 result = m * t;
```